# Efficiency of the PV inverter

Tags: batteries, inverter, solar-energy

I'm doing a little university project in which I'm projecting a small PV plant of 50 kW. When I produce more power than my load need, I want to store the solar power inside the battery. Should I consider both the efficiency of the inverter and of the battery in order to calculate the net power stored?

Comment: I would think that you can use either as long as you make it clear which you're using.

Comment: @Transistor sorry man I don't understand your answer. Should I use both of them?

Comment: Sorry, that comment was badly worded and answered a question that you didn't ask! Yes, consider both.

Comment: @Transistor thank you very much!

Comment: You must have an energy and power budget for every component with Losses including battery ESR and MPT error voltage , PV alignment error, Location Solarity, required storage to prevent brownout ,  a load profile charger efficiency and much more. Worst case charging a battery from 0 to 100% will equal the total energy that the battery can store in Joules or 50% effiviency